# Android - Make border for drawablebitmap as Marker in MapView

Tags: java, android, base64, border, android-drawable

I want to make border or stroke for the drawableBitMap that is converted from base64 string to image. Can someone help me to do this? Here is my sample code:

```
String base64String = facilitiesOverlayProperties.get(i).getImage();
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable  = new BitmapDrawable(map.getContext().getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedByte, 26, 26, false));
                    mapMarker.setIcon(bitmapDrawable);
```

The code for creating border or stroke is still not there since I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you need a circular border around your marker ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a circular border around your bitmap using this:

```
//mMap is your GoogleMap Refrence

mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).radius(10)
            .strokeColor(0x220000FF)//stroke color
            .strokeWidth(5)
            .fillColor(0x220000FF));//your fill colour
```

Comment: How can I use that in MapView? I am using an osm map, not the google map